# Eclipse error in C project

Tags: c, eclipse

I am new to C programming. I just installed Eclipse CDT and Cygwin. I tried to run this code. But showing 3 errors in problems window of eclipse.

Errors:

```
1- make:***[CProject.exe]Error 1
2- recipe for target 'Cproject.exe'failed
3- Undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'
```

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
printf("I want to be a competent C programmer");
return 0;
}
```

I don't know what to do, Can anyone help me?

Comment: Post your code and project settings please.

Comment: I think you created Windows application . Make your project as console application . That should fix it .

Answer (score 1):

Set the project type to console application and try again.

Comment: Thank you Magisch. This resolved previous error message but I got some new error messages.

Comment: make:*** No rule to make target 'all'.stop

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile and execute it with you're command line,

```
gcc yourfile.c
./a.out
```

if you don't have gcc, you can install it there : http://www.matpack.de/cygwin/index.html